# Are 32-bit libraries installable on Ubuntu 16.04 for Android development?

Tags: apt, 16.04, dependencies, android, android-studio

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 but I am stuck because the distribution can not install the 32-bit libraries `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`.

My output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or I should just revert to 15.04?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and `apt policy lib32stdc++6 gcc-5-base lib32gcc1 libc6-i386`. Also don't forget to run `sudo apt update` before trying to install packages. And no, 15.04 is no longer supported and you should not downgrade to this release.

Comment: FYI, you do need those libraries, and your build will fail without them.

Comment: is a problem solved?

Comment: Only `lib32stdc++6` was needed in my case and it got installed without any issues. Did you perform a clean install of 16.04 or upgrade from 15.10?